# Remove and add compression in kafka topic. What will happen to the existing data in the topic?

Tags: apache-kafka

If a topic is set without `compression`, and some data already exist in the topic.
Now the topic is set with `compression`, will the existing data be compressed?

The other direction is, if a topic is set with `compression`, and some data already exist in the topic, will the existing data be decompressed?

This question comes up the worries to the data consumer. When the topic has some data is compressed and some is not compressed, this is very messy, or the brokers know those events are compressed and those are not in the same topic, and will deliver the right data?

If the existing data is not corresponding to the compression setup, I will remove the existing data by configuring very low retention time. Until the topic is very clean that has no data, I will then ingest data to ensure every event is either compressed or not compressed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both compressed and uncompressed records could coexist in a single topic. The corresponding compression type is stored in each record（record batch actually）, so the consumer knows how to handle this message.

On the broker side, it normally does not care if a record batch is compressed. Assuming there occurs no down converting for old-formatted records, the broker always saves the batch as it is.

Comment: sounds good. did you know is there more explanation documented somewhere?

Comment: Check it out for some explanation of this:https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#design_compression